# XMLHttpRequest request / Servlet response is null

Tags: ajax, servlets

There is a problem with servlet. I send form data by XMLHttpRequest to a server, but servlet handles request object incorrectly and send in response object "null.null". I tried following things but nothing helps:

- encode "document.getElementsByName('contractor').value" by encodeURIComponent;
- pass the object of FormData as argument to .send();
- changing enctype attribute in form to "multipart/formdata";
- using get method.

Please take a look. If there are any suggestions how to make it works without using jQuery I would appreciate a lot.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="request-form">
    <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
        Contractor<input type="text" name="contractor"><br>
        Contract No<input type="text" name="contract-no">
        <input type="button" onclick=clickOnButton() value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var httpRequest;

function clickOnButton() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var dataForRequest = 'contract=' + document.getElementsByName('contractor').value + '&contract-no=' + document.getElementsByName('contract-no').value;
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseHandler;
    httpRequest.open('POST', "/AjaxServ", true);
    httpRequest.send(dataForRequest);
}

function responseHandler() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
            var line = httpRequest.responseText;
            alert(line);
        }
    }
}
```

**Java:**

```
public class ServletClass extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String contractor = req.getParameter("contractor");
        String contractNo = req.getParameter("contract-no");
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write(contractor + "." + contractNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: `httpRequest.open('POST', "/AjaxServ", true);` will not include the context path.

Comment: I mean that if you are testing your project on `http://localhost/project/testpage` and your post is on `/AjaxServ`, it will post at `http://localhost/AjaxServ` so you will get a 404 error, you can try it with Firebug (Network) or whatever tool to see HTTP requests

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `'contractor=' + document.getElementsByName('contractor').value` instead of 
`'contract=' + document.getElementsByName('contractor').value` ?